# How to return fields in query based on an other query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my situation, I have a grid in an angular app which displays data. All works fine and I am able to let the user select which column's are displayed in the grid, but since I hide them on client I still get some blank column's. To fix that I have to remove the undesired columns from my returned query. So much to prefix here is what i have. Query one will return me all column a user wants to see in query.

```
DECLARE @Txt1 VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Txt1=''

SELECT  @Txt1 = @Txt1 + tblA.column_name +','
FROM   [tbl_gridcolumns] as tblA
left join [dbo].[tbl_griduser] as tblB
on tblA.guid = tblB.column_guid
where tblA.master_guid = '43A4ED59-3515-4A19-B919-863D15A3DCBB' and 
tblb.user_guid = '8D6D24A5-D669-45DC-99AC-F257BDA133A4' and display =1

SELECT  LEFT(@Txt1,LEN(@Txt1)-1) AS txt
```

this returns me the value txt as

> uid,sano,sapd,sasn,city,state,zip,carrier_route,fo_fullname,owner_absent_occupied,tract_number

so good so far now i want to be able to use the txt value as a list column's i want to return in my stored procedure which looks like this.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getFarmCount]    
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@p_offset as int = 0,
@p_nbrrows as int = 50,
@p_sasn as Varchar(50),
@p_city as varchar(50),
@p_fo_full_name as varchar(150),
@p_carrier_route as varchar(10),
@p_tract_number as varchar(50),
@p_owner_absent_occupied as varchar(1)
AS
 SELECT 
 // this static part of columns i would like to replace with the dynamic 
 list which is stored in txt
   [uid]
  ,[sano]
  ,[sapd]
  ,[sasn]
  ,[city]
  ,[state]
  ,[zip]
  ,[carrier_route]
  ,[fo_fullname]
  ,[mailing_addr]
  ,[mailing_city]
  ,[mailing_state]
  ,[mailing_zip]
  ,[saun]
  ,[sqft_structure]
  ,[rooms]
  ,[sale_value]
  ,[sale_date]
  ,[lot_sqft]
  ,[year_build]
  ,[owner_absent_occupied]
  ,[tract_number]
  // End od static column list

 FROM [cmr_crm].[dbo].[tbl_FarmMaster]

 where sasn like CONCAT(@p_sasn, '%')  
 and city like CONCAT(@p_city, '%')  
 and fo_fullname like CONCAT('%', @p_fo_full_name, '%')  
 and carrier_route like CONCAT(@p_carrier_route, '%')   
 and tract_number like CONCAT(@p_tract_number, '%')  
 and owner_absent_occupied like CONCAT(@p_owner_absent_occupied, '%')

 order by Sasn,cast(sano as int) 
 OFFSET @p_offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @p_nbrrows ROWS ONLY
```

How would I go about achieving this, for one I need to put the first Query in the stored procedure or would I make 2 and then return then call the first one from the 2nd one and use result?

Comment: You can use sp_executesql to build and run your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_executeSQL to build and run such a dynamic SQL. ie:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getFarmCount]    
@collist as varchar(4000),
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@p_offset as int = 0,
@p_nbrrows as int = 50,
@p_sasn as Varchar(50),
@p_city as varchar(50),
@p_fo_full_name as varchar(150),
@p_carrier_route as varchar(10),
@p_tract_number as varchar(50),
@p_owner_absent_occupied as varchar(1)
AS
 begin

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000);  
DECLARE @definition nvarchar(1000);  

SET @sql =  N'SELECT ' + @collist +
       'from myTable    
       WHERE someColumn = @someParameter';

SET @definition = N'@someParameter int';  

SET @IntVariable = 197;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @definition,  
                      @someParameter = @p_offset; 

end
```

(@p_offset was just an arbitrary sample)

Comment: thanks that made some stuff more clear and i was able to pass the column list successfully into my query. But i am having problem with where clause getting a 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'. which doesn't tell me much so i simplified my query but still cant find the cause

Comment: @MisterniceGuy, try printing the @ sql.

Answer (score 0):

After some forth and back i ended up with the following solution which works as expected and is less complicated because of the nbr of parm i have. There is alway more then one way to do things. Maybe this helps someone

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getFarmCountTest] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@p_offset as int = 0,
@p_nbrrows as int = 50,
@p_sasn as Varchar(50),
@p_city as varchar(50),
@p_fo_full_name as varchar(150),
@p_carrier_route as varchar(10),
@p_tract_number as varchar(50),
@p_owner_absent_occupied as varchar(1)
AS

BEGIN

Declare @val Varchar(MAX);

---Take the First query  result into temp table ---

select
tblA.column_name
INTO #temp
from [tbl_gridcolumns] as tblA
left join [dbo].[tbl_griduser] as tblB
on tblA.guid = tblB.column_guid
where tblA.master_guid = '43A4ED59-3515-4A19-B919-863D15A3DCBB' and tblb.user_guid = '8D6D24A5-D669-45DC-99AC-F257BDA133A4' and display =1

--join the values retuned from first query
Select @val = COALESCE(@val + ', ' + column_name, column_name) From  #temp
Select @val;

SET @val= 'Select '+ @val +
' FROM [cmr_crm].[dbo].[tbl_FarmMaster] '+
' where sasn like '+''''+ CONCAT(@p_sasn, '%') +''''+
' and city like '+ ''''+CONCAT(@p_city, '%') +''''+
' and fo_fullname like '+ ''''+ CONCAT('%', @p_fo_full_name, '%')+''''+
' and carrier_route like '+ ''''+CONCAT(@p_carrier_route, '%')+''''+
' and tract_number like '+ ''''+CONCAT(@p_tract_number, '%')+''''+
' and owner_absent_occupied like '+ ''''+CONCAT(@p_owner_absent_occupied, '%')+''''+

' order by Sasn,cast(sano as int) '+
'OFFSET ' +Convert(VARCHAR(100),@p_offset) +' ROWS FETCH NEXT '+ 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@p_nbrrows) + ' ROWS ONLY '


 Execute (@val)
```